# Is EmbeddedFileProvider or ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider available in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have seen references in documentation ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.1 ) to `EmbeddedFileProvider` and  `ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider` as a way of accessing embedded resource files in my assembly via the `IFileProvider` interface, but when I try to use either of them I get "Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" and the only options in VS alt+enter menu are to generate the class.

I have already specified `using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;` and `PhysicalFileProvider` is certainly available, but not the embedded ones. 
If they are supposed to be usable in 2.1 how do I make them available to my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following NuGet package: [Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded).